# Magento admin logs out when upload an image via CMS WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: image-upload, wysiwyg, ee-1.11

After installing Magento patch `SUPEE-8788` there's an issue in CMS page  WYSIWYG editor. When I try to upload an image via  WYSIWYG editor, it automatically logs out from the admin panel. My Magento version is `EE 1.11.2.0`

Have anyone else encountered this issue? Any suggestions to solve this would be appreciated.